# Avoid another meta box in my custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

I created my own custom post, all right up here.
I have also added the meta box for custom post.
But I've noticed that some plugins automatically add their own METABOX my custom post type.

This can be avoided?

Kind Regars.

Comment: You first need to know all parameters with plugin resister meta boxes to use [`remove_meta_box()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has remove_meta_box() function. You can use it to remove meta box

like

```
function remove_post_meta_box() {
    remove_meta_box( 'meta_box_id' , 'post' , 'normal' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_post_meta_box' );
```